# How to get range and then set value in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a function on edit that will look for the value 'c' in a range of cells and then replace it with the word 'Closed'.

This is what I have so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('CA12:CA15').getValues();
  var closed = 'c'
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
  if(data[i] == closed) {

    Logger.log('yes')
    Logger.log(data[i]);    
  }
    }
  }
```

So this is successfully logging 'yes' and the value 'c' when I have this value within the given range. But how do I now replace this value?

I tried storing the range of data[i] using getRange() but it won't allow me to do this. If I can get this range then I know I can then use range.setValue('Closed') but a bit stuck at the moment. I know I'm doing something very simple very wrong but any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

#### Key points:

- `getValues` returns a 2 dimensional array ordered by rows and then columns. You're accessing a 1D array with `data[i]`
- `i` the index of array + start row is equal to the current row in loop.

#### Code snippet(slow):

```
if(data[i][0] == closed) { //2D
 sheet.getRange('CA'+(12+i)).setValue('Closed');
}
```

- But the above is slow, because we're calling setValue() for each true condition. Better way is to use arrays.

#### Code snippet(fast 70x):

```
var rng =sheet.getRange('CA12:CA15');
var data = rng.getValues();
var output = data.map(function(e) { return e[0] == closed ? ['Closed'] : e });
rng.setValues(output); //Single call
```

- Fastest way is to use Find and Replace either from the sheets UI or API

#### Essential Reading:

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [2D array](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)
- [FR API request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#FindReplaceRequest)

Comment: Thank you very much - the first option actually works well for me, although I understand it is not too efficient. However, I have one more issue. The data range I need to look at is actually the entire sheet rather than just CA12:CA15. However, when I try to extend the range it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var editedCell=sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),e.range.getColumn()).getA1Notation();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var found=false;
  var foundA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

    if(data[i][2] == 'c') {
      found=true;
      foundA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  if(found){
    Logger.log('Matches found in following rows of column C: %s\nCell Edited was: %s',foundA.join(','),editedCell);
  }else{
    Logger.log('No matches found');
  }

}
```

For testing purposes you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Logger.getLog());` to display Logger results.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues();
  var name = valuetosearchincColumnC;
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i] == name) {
      
      var id = i + 2;// plus two bec i have a header
      sheet.getRange(id,2).setValue('ValuetoChange');
    }
  }
```