# Converting Google Sheets IF formula to Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As a test, I have entered the following formula in cell K2 of my spreadsheet: `=IF($M2=today(),"Today")`. This acheives the desired effect and I would like this to be applied to all the rows below (with m3 referring to k3 , m4 to k4 etc.) , HOWEVER, this sheet is updated via Google Form so I cannot leave a formula in these cells as it will be overwritten.

Therefore I need to write and run the formula in apps script but, whilst I have enough knowledge of script language to do write basic If functions, this one is beyond my skills.

I have referred to this: [How to get range and then set value in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538956/how-to-get-range-and-then-set-value-in-google-apps-script) and tried to adapt it to my purposes but to no avail.

Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: can you show a sample sheet and provide the behavior you'd like to achieve? like what cells are to be modified, their outputs and other details we might need to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
function isMToday() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get M2:M range
  mRange = sheet.getRange(2, 13, lastRow - 1, 1);
  // get display values instead to avoid timezone issues
  mValues = mRange.getDisplayValues();
  today = new Date();

  // check every mValue, if today, return today, else false
  output = mValues.map(mValue => {
    mValueDate = new Date(mValue);
    if (mValueDate.getDate() == today.getDate() &&
        mValueDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() &&
        mValueDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear())
      return ["Today"];
    else 
      return [false];
  });

  // write output to K2:K
  mRange.offset(0, -2).setValues(output);
}
```

After execution:

[image: after]

Comment: That's great, the only thing I would like is to adjust the date format. I see you have it as M/DD/YYYY but I am in the UK so would appreciate If you could let me know how to amend it to DD/MM/YYYY? Thanks!

Comment: it should still work with it @Xanthippus480, did you try running it on your file?

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back to you - I am not sure why but it doesn't work in both formats, only m/dd/yyyy?

Comment: EDIT: Ignore me, just tried it again and it does in fact work as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need AppScript to do this even though it is on a Form Responses tab.

Instead of this formula in cell K2 (as you described):

```
=IF($M2=today(),"Today")
```

Use this formula in cell K1, and delete all the other formulas in column K:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(M:M)=1,"Today?",IF(M:M=TODAY(),"Today")))
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's a good idea, definitely something I'll use in other projects, but unfortunately I failed to mention that I already have other data in the column that comes in from the form, therefore the Array Formula will not work as it won't overwrite existing data.